# Create daily ingestion alerts on Grafana LOKI for top clients sending logs

Tags: logging, monitor, grafana-loki, logql

Is there any way to know how much data is being pushed to Grafana Loki by each application?

Comment: I don't think Loki has an idea of which client (app) you use to push logs. But if each "app" pushes to _a tenant_, you can achieve what you need with Loki Ruler and something like: `sum by (tenant) (increase(loki_distributor_bytes_received_total[24h]))`, which will report what is the increase of log volumes, by bytes, in the last 24h _per tenant_

Answer (score 1):

The following query, for example, will count the number of log lines with label "group" equal to "tools" and totalize them by label "instance":

```
sum by(instance) (count_over_time({group="tools"} [24h]))
```

You can see only the top 10 ones, for example:

```
topk(10, sum by(instance) (count_over_time({group="tools"} [24h])))
```

Comment: Hi Marcelo,

I can see that this gives us the number of lines written to Loki. 

I have a different scenario. Let's say my app is making 1GB of logs per day and pushing this to Loki. I want to know these metrics from Loki, and based on which app sends the most logs I want to send daily alerts. 

Is that provision available in Loki?

Comment: See here: https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/rules/

Comment: This is great. We can Identify who is pushing more log lines.

Answer (score 0):

Found one solution that works for my issue.

```
promtail_file_bytes_total
```

This metric will give the amount of data that has been pushed to Loki from promtail.

But the issue is that these metrics only have data about the nodes.

like this

```
promtail_file_bytes_total{Env="prod"
app_kubernetes_io_instance="loki-distributed"
app_kubernetes_io_name="promtail"
cluster="prod-cluster"
cluster_name="prod-cluster"
controller_revision_hash="bf54474f9"
instance="10.200.16.204:3101"
job="kubernetes-pods"
kubernetes_namespace="<logging ns>"
kubernetes_pod_name="loki-distributed-promtail-<ID>"
origin_prometheus="production-cluster"
path="/var/log/pods/<namespace>_<podname>_<deployemntID>-<some other IDs>/0.log"
pod_template_generation="6"}
```

but the path label has the file path that contains the details about the application.

I have used the `label_replace` option to create a new label with the application name.

```
sum (label_replace(sort_desc(delta(promtail_file_bytes_total{path =~ "/var/log/pods/.*().*"}[24h])),  "app", "$1", "path", "/var/log/pods/(.*_.{9})-.*" )) by (app) /1024/1024
```

Another option is to use recording rules that are built in on Prometheus or Grafana.